# What are underscore names in Kotlin reserved for?

Tags: kotlin

In Python you can use `_` as a variable name. If I write e.g. `val _ = 3` in Kotlin IntelliJ gives me an error with:

```
Names _, __, ___, ..., are reserved in Kotlin
```

What are they reserved for? What is their function?

Comment: Underscore is for unused variables. For more information [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#underscore-for-unused-variables-since-11).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The single underscore is already used in several ways where you want to skip a parameter or a component and don't want to give it a name:

- For [ignoring parameters in lambda expressions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#underscore-for-unused-variables-since-11):

  ```kotlin
  val l = listOf(1, 2, 3)
  l.forEachIndexed { index, _ -> println(index) }
  ```
- For [unused components in destructuring declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html#underscore-for-unused-variables-since-11):

  ```kotlin
  val p = Pair(1, 2)
  val (first, _) = p
  ```
- For ignoring an exception in a `try`-`catch` statement:

  ```kotlin
  try {
      /* ... */
  } catch (_: IOException) {
      /* ... */
  }
  ```
- (**since Kotlin 1.7**) For [omitting the type arguments](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#underscore-operator-for-type-arguments) that the compiler is supposed to infer based on the context:

  ```kotlin
  val s = Runner.run<SomeImplementation, _>()
  ```
- As [@Willi Mentzel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1788806/willi-mentzel) noted in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59966334/what-are-underscore-names-in-kotlin-reserved-for/59966431?noredirect=1#comment106051438_59966431), another use of underscores, though not in a position of an identifier, is [separating digit groups in numeric literals](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#underscores-in-numeric-literals-since-11):

  val oneMillion = 1_000_000
  val creditCardNumber = 1234_5678_9012_3456L

Some of these syntax forms were introduced in Kotlin 1.1, and that's why the underscore names had been reserved before Kotlin 1.1. The multiple-underscore names like `__`, `___` had also been reserved so that they are not misused where previously one would have used a single-underscore name.

Comment: Thats the correct answer, but if you still want to use it for some reason you can escape it using backticks  `  _  `

Comment: as an addition: they can be used to make number constants more readable: 10_000 instead of 10000 (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#underscores-in-numeric-literals-since-11).

Comment: Also generic type inference, e.x. `Map<String, _>`